# How do I update an entire row based on a condition using a trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper

I want to update an entire row based on a condition using a trigger. I am trying this condition, which is not working

```
create or replace trigger cust_person_merge_view_t
 instead of update on CUST_MDM_PERSON_MERGE
 referencing new as new
 begin
      update mdm_person_tt 
      set :old.row = :new.row;
      where MDM_PARTY_ID =(select mdm_party_id from CUST_MDM_PERSON_MERGE where mdm_entity_id=:old.MDM_ENTITY_ID);
     if ( sql%rowcount = 0 )
       then
         raise_application_error
          ( -20001, 'Error updating the CUST_MDM_PERSON_MERGE view !!!' );
     end if;
 end;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is your database version? Are CUST_MDM_PERSON_MERGE and mdm_person_tt identical? Please provide more pertinent information in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference an entire row using :old and :new. You will have to assign the values column by column.